# Bootstrap : Setting position absolute for inner container

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I've a parent div that is set to position relative and a container inside is that a div that has a background color and is set to position absolute so that it's always at the bottom of the container, but it's not being set to bottom  see my code (I'm adding inline CSS to get clear understanding).

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12" style="position: relative;">
  <h3>Category Title </h3>
  <h1>Heading </h1>
  <h1>90 Mins</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
  <p>
  <!-- now this is position absolute div  -->
  <div class="innner" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;">
    <h4>Tonight on  Tv</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <h4>7:30PM</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <h5>Program Titles Comes Here</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**This is what I get if I set `position:absolute`:**
[image]

here is link to bootply : http://www.bootply.com/dRifoRP7Q6

Comment: It looks like it's at the bottom to me - if all you have in the outer is the paragraph of text then this is working as it should - if it's not, can you make a bootply to show in more detail

Comment: okay adding to bootply

Comment: @DarrenSweeney i updated my question with link to bootply code please check that

Comment: As I said, its working as it should - if you look in your inspector, the bottom of the relative div is where your absolute element is attached to, at the bottom of it - change `style="position: relative;"` to `style="position: relative; height: 350px"` and you'll see what I mean

Answer (score 1):

Put the content in class="row"

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
  <div class="row">
    <h3>Category Title </h3>
    <h1>Heading </h1>
    <h1>90 Mins</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
      Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- now this is position absolute div  -->
  <div class="row" style="background: #dab13b; float:left;">
    <h4>Tonight on  Tv</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <h4>7:30PM</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <h5>Program Titles Comes Here</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sir this is gonna be  dynamic content , thats not the way to   deal this

Answer (score -1):

use the position as "static" for the parent div instead of relative.

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12" style="position: static;">
```

Comment: Is this not working Sikander ? changing the position to static for the parent div..

Comment: that works but does not seem to be proper soution because causes issues with  alignmet of inner div

Comment: does not work in responsive mode thats not the way to do it causing issues

Comment: what do you mean alignment of inner div ? kindly elaborate your requirement

Comment: please check bootply link thats in my question  you can play with it that will clear the idea

Comment: do you mean there other contents in the page , and you want the inner div to appear at the bottom of its parent div not the at the bottom of the page ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107102/discussion-between-sikander-and-enthusiast).

Comment: there are two panels lef and right left is col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12 so  even if left one gets more height right one should have specific section to its bottom section thats what i mean